# Civicase Report?

Tags: civicase, custom-reports

> I am very new to Civicrm, and have gotten a lot figured out and some
>   fixes applied on my own.
>
> I am trying to figure out the report features... and maybe very basic
>   - but.
>
> I am looking to create a report from CIVICASE that lists all the notes
>   for a Case. If there is a tutorial i am very happy to explore that as
>   well, just at a loss for where to look.

Ok I had some time to read more of the forums - and the numerous posts on reporting with Civicase and Civicrm - and i looked at your responses below, but they did not help with my question (made a little more sense, but didn't get what i was looking for)

So I am going to clarify what i am looking for:

1. I need to print an individual report for a Single Case.
2. I need to be able to format the Header of the Report to include:
      Name of Client, Address, Phone 
      Case Manager, (any other assigned roles to that case)
3. The report information would be a list of dates (for the NOTES activity)
   Date    Person who wrote Note and the "details" of that note.
   All sorted by Date.

I have looked at Views - but i found that even more confusing. Any direction would be great.

Comment: OK.. I see what you are talking about, but  that's not what i mean. I need to create a report for One Case (at a time) that Give the Client's name some contact information and then a dated inventory (maybe not a good word to use) of Notes (which i currently have as an Activity)  it would give the "Date" of the Note , the "Case Worker" -Role who wrote the note and the actual text of the note. And make it look nice. I am very new to Civicrm - and I really don't get how the reporting works and how to customize a report to suit our needs.

Comment: The print report button as mentioned in the answer seems to be what you're asking?

Comment: After your edit, except for being able to rearrange the header format, this still sounds really similar to the output from the Print Report link that appears on Manage Case. I'll see if I can post a screenshot in the answer if it's not clear what action I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean just for a given single case, then there is the Print Report button on the "third row" of the Manage Case screen.

[image]
[image]

If you want to edit the layout look at CRM/Case/XMLProcessor/Report.php and templates/CRM/Case/XMLProcessor/Report.tpl.

If you mean from some subset of cases then I don't think there is one specifically to search on case parameters and output the notes, but you could start with the activity detail report and on the columns tab check activity details (I assume that's what you mean by "notes" - the details fields on the activities), and on the filters tab choose Include Case Activities, and then possibly filter the date ranges and contacts.

Also the output of Find Cases contains a small triangle in the leftmost column of the result table. Clicking on that triangle shows the activities, although not the details field of the activities.

Comment: Sorry taken a while to get back to this... Ok Yes that report has the meat of what i want - but where came if find the .tpl and .php for that report. I want to be able to filter out certain activities from that report. That gives All the activities - i want to be able to filter out only some. I have been reading about creating custom reports - very daunting, but i think if i can find files represented by the above report i may be able to edit it to meet my needs...

Comment: I've edited the answer - CRM/Case/XMLProcessor/Report.xxx